# SVG circle and line transition not working

Tags: html, css, svg, transition

I'm trying to implement a simple toggle based on an SVG icon. However, I'm not able to get `transition` work on either circle or line, although is does for the parent. I think it might be redundant to add `circle` and `line` to `transition`, but I still did, just to be sure.

```css
svg, circle, line {
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

svg:hover {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

svg:hover circle {
  fill: #d5f0e5;
  stroke: #00884e;
}

svg:hover line {
  stroke: #00884e;
}
```

```html
<svg width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<circle cx="10" cy="10" r="9.5" stroke="#515663"/>
<line x1="10.0555" y1="5" x2="10.0555" y2="15" stroke="#2A303E"/>
<line x1="5" y1="9.94434" x2="15" y2="9.94434" stroke="#2A303E"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The stroke color transitions do work, but .2s is really fast, maybe that's why you thought it wasn't working?
However, you can't transition from <color>`none` to non-none <color>, you need to set it to `transparent` if you want the interpolation to work:

```css
svg, circle, line {
  transition: all 2s ease-in-out; /* set to 2s to clearly show if it works */
}

svg:hover {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

svg:hover circle {
  fill: #d5f0e5;
  stroke: #00884e;
}

svg:hover line {
  stroke: #00884e;
}
```

```html
<!-- changed the 'fill' attribute from "none" to "transparent" to allow transitionning -->
<svg width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="transparent" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <circle cx="10" cy="10" r="9.5" stroke="#515663"/>
  <line x1="10.0555" y1="5" x2="10.0555" y2="15" stroke="#2A303E"/>
  <line x1="5" y1="9.94434" x2="15" y2="9.94434" stroke="#2A303E"/>
</svg>
```

Or as commented below, you could also play with the `fill-opacity` property for the same effect and probably better browser support.

Comment: wouldn't it be better to leave the fill alone and transition the fill-opacity?

Comment: @RobertLongson yes could be (I guess it would improve browser support), just pointing out the "why" it doesn't work. From there building workarounds is up to the situation.